# Two "spam" flags are "disputed", but the posts have vanished, what happened?

Tags: support

Yesterday I flagged two "answers" as spam. On reviewing my flags I saw both were *disputed*, so I wanted to look at them again to reevaluate - but both are gone. What happened?

- [How do I move (copy) my entire Ubuntu system to a different hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151127/how-do-i-move-copy-my-entire-ubuntu-system-to-a-different-hard-disk/768724#768724)
- [Do I need a server for hosting website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769136/do-i-need-a-server-for-hosting-website/769341#769341)

Comment: Your first option was manually deleted by a moderator (Seth), the second one got deleted by spam flags. That's what I can see from the deleted posts, no idea how that resulted in your disputed flag status though... Maybe your spam flags aged away without getting confirmed or declined by enough people and the posts got re-flagged and finally deleted later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happened:

You flagged each post as spam. A moderator reviewed your flags and decided they were not spam. Other people came by and flagged the posts as NAA. Different moderators reviewed those flags and deleted the posts.

Neither appeared to be spam to me (although one was kinda close). One was definitely NAA. I've undeleted the other because it is actually a legitimate attempt to answer the question (and not spam).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - confusion happens :-)
I still have my doubts about the validity of an answer that contains the names of 4 companies, the term "professionals like" AND the catchword *reseller*.

Comment: @guntbert Well they are clean links for well known and competing companies.. and the overall answers makes sense so..

Comment: I **knew** you would find convincing words ;-)